# <body> not covering full screen

Tags: html, css

excuse me if this question is answered before. I tried some options but none of them is working for me.

I am using Css grid areas properties but body tag is not covering the full screen view and cut off at the bottom. I want line and content should move down to the bottom and cover the full screen.

Here is the code,

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="mainmenu">
            <site-logo>
                <a href="./index.html"><img class="logo" src="SemG-Logo-Final-01small-2.png"></a>
                <p>Full Stack Developer</p>
                <p>Web Apps | E-Commerce</p>
            </site-logo>
            <div>
                <nav class="menuitem">
                    <li><a href="./index.html" title="">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="./index.html" title="">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="./index.html" title="">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="./index.html" title="">Contact Us</a></li>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="socialicon">
                <a href="https://twitter.com/"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/"><i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i></a>
                <a href="https://twitter.com/"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a>
            </div>



            <hr>
            <div class="copyright">
                <p>© 2018 I Click Digital Ltd <br> All rights reserved</p>
            </div>
        </div>

body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    height: 100%;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

when setting a percentage value to the height of an element, the browser will look at the parent's height to calculate it.

setting `body { height:100% }` doesn't get the body to stretch across the document, because it's parent `<html>` height equals to 0, therefore 100% of that is 0.

obvious answer here it to set  `html { height:100% }` but what is the parent of the root element `<html>` here you should read about [The Initial Containing Block](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#containing-block-details)

the `<html>` parent is basically the `viewport` the red box you see below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create a new `div` with fixed position and put `hr` and `.copyright` div inside that fixed div.

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    height: 100%;

}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="mainmenu">
            <site-logo>
                <p>Full Stack Developer</p>
                <p>Web Apps | E-Commerce</p>
            </site-logo>
            <div>
                <nav class="menuitem">
                    <li><a href="./index.html" title="">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="./index.html" title="">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="./index.html" title="">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="./index.html" title="">Contact Us</a></li>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="socialicon">
                <a href="https://twitter.com/"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/"><i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i></a>
                <a href="https://twitter.com/"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a>
            </div>



            <div class="footer">
              <hr>
              <div class="copyright">
                  <p>© 2018 I Click Digital Ltd <br> All rights reserved</p>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: View the snippet in full screen to see the effect properly.